# Reacat | FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hope you are doing great.

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see in the above firestore rule, I have allowed all users to be able to write and read data from firestore database. The thing is I still got the error of Missing or insufficient permissions. Actually it worked until last night and I started to get this error from today. Anyone who got stuck with such problem before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Update it to:

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

This will allow full access to everyone